# How do I fix the position of an input so it's always below an element that's centered on the screen but its size can change?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have an element in my UI called a `SkyElement`, which is always vertically and horizontally centered in my UI. I also have an input, called a `PencilInput` that's I want to always be below the `SkyElement`.

In the UI, the user has the ability to change the size (width and height) of the `SkyElement` and I want the `PencilInput` to be positioned below the `SkyElement`, regardless of size.

Right now, the `PencilInput` is displaying above the `SkyElement`, regardless of size.

In my `render` function:

```
<div className="left-side">
    <SkyElement />

    <PencilInput />
</div>
```

The HTML of `PencilInput`:

```
<div className='pencil-input-holder'>
    <div className='pencil-svg' />

    <input className='pencil-input' onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.title} />
</div>
```

In my css:

```
@mixin absolute-center {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.left-side {
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #000000 0%, #205F8A 45.56%, #8852BB 100%);
    position: relative;

    .element {
        @include absolute-center;
        transform: scale(1.3);
        transform-origin: center center;
    }
}

.pencil-input-holder {
    border-bottom: 4px dashed rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;

    .pencil-svg {
        background: url('../images/pencil.svg') center center no-repeat;
        width: 27px;
        height: 39px;
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        top: 60px;
        left: 20px;
    }
}

input.pencil-input {
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'GT America Compressed Regular';
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 59px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    background: transparent;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    border: none;

    &:focus { outline: none; }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit: Added `render()` block of `SkyElement`**

Aside from the code below and the `.left-side .element` code above, that's the entirety of the css for the `SkyElement`

```
render() {
    const { connectDragSource, isDragging, hideSourceOnDrag, transformElement, top, left } = this.props;

    // hide on drag in slot view
    if (isDragging && hideSourceOnDrag) {
        return null;
    }

    const halfSize = this.props.size / 2;
    const transform = transformElement ? `translate(-50%, -50%)` : '';

    const style = {
        width: `${this.props.size}px`,
        height: `${this.props.size}px`,
        borderRadius: '50%',
        background: this.radialGradient(),
        opacity: isDragging ? 0.2 : this.props.opacity,
        boxShadow: this.boxShadow(),
        transform,
        transition: 'background 0.2s',
        position: 'relative',
        top,
        left,
    };

    return connectDragSource(
        <div onClick={this.editElement} className='element' style={style}>
            {
                this.props.labelPosition
                    ? <ElementLabel title={this.props.title} position={this.props.labelPosition } />
                    : null
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you share an example of the SkyElement output and related CSS?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody added

Comment: Sounds like the `<SkyElement />` and `<PencilInput />` elements are somewhat connected then, at least visually - since you always want the input to be below the SkyElement. Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct. I tried putting the `PencilInput` inside of the `SkyElement` html but the input was showing up inside of the SkyElement rather than below it. I basically always want the input below SkyElement regardless of the width/height (which has the ability to change via a slider within this view)

Comment: Because if I put `PencilInput` inside of `SkyElement` than it takes its width which I don't want since the input value could be wider than the `SkyElement`

Comment: flexbox is your friend. Also checkout css-grid (this is what i use to accomplish similar tasks).

Answer (score 5):

One issue I see with your current solution, your `@mixin` is setup incorrectly. It produces 2 `transform` properties, which results in only one being applied:

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: scale(1.3);
```

This should be written as:

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.3);
```

**However**, that is not the only issue. My recommendation would be to wrap the `<SkyElement/>` and `<PencilInput/>` in a wrapper component/element to center the group of elements horizontally/vertically.

```
<div className="left-side">
  <CenterElements>
    <SkyElement />
    <PencilInput />
  </CenterElements>
</div>
```

or

```
<div className="left-side">
  <div class="center">
    <SkyElement />
    <PencilInput />
  </div>
</div>
```

This element/component will contain the styles to horizontally and vertically center it.

I've attempted to use the existing CSS to show how this could be done. This will need to be converted back into Sass if you prefer that. The basic idea is to wrap the `<SkyElement/>` and `<PencilInput/>` in a wrapper element and center that vertically. You can then position the `.pencil-input-holder` element using `position: absolute;` within that. The `<SkyElement/>`'s size will not effect the size of the `<PencilInput/>` element with this implementation.

Something along these lines:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.left-side {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #000000 0%, #205F8A 45.56%, #8852BB 100%);
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.element-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.left-side .element {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.5);
}

.pencil-input-holder {
  border-bottom: 4px dashed rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.pencil-input-holder .pencil-svg {
  background: url("../images/pencil.svg") center center no-repeat;
  width: 27px;
  height: 39px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
  left: 20px;
}

input.pencil-input {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'GT America Compressed Regular';
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 59px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  background: transparent;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border: none;
}

input.pencil-input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-side">
  <div class="element-container">
    <div class="element" style="position: relative;">
      Sky
    </div>
    <div class="pencil-input-holder">
      <div class="pencil-svg">
        Pencil
      </div>

      <input class="pencil-input" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.title} />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend wrapping them and applying flex.

```
 <div style={{divstyle}}>
   <component1/>
   <component2/> 
 </div>

divstyle = {
  display:'flex',
  justify-content:'center',
  align-items:'center',
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about using `display: flex`? with this `centerBox` div

```
.centerBox {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Full Example is here:
https://codepen.io/kkpoon/pen/rzNraz